# I need details explaination about " BLOCKCHAIN BITCOIN ADDER BOT"

Tags: blockchain, private-key

I saw this file titled "
BLOCKCHAIN BITCOIN ADDER" on facebook and i tried to follow the process by importing the wallet that was given. On doing that I received a lots of bitcoin that i never dream i can earn. At the end of the file the private key was given without the password. Payment was asked in order to give the password. As per me i don't have upto 2dollar worth of bitcoin not to talk of the 20 dollar that was asking.

I want to know if this method of earning of bitcoin is possible. More than 3BTC is sucked in blockchain wallet. Another curiosity is that payment is keeping on entering the wallet. There is no day i won't received a payment to the wallet.

Is this possible, real and genuine  ? Is it possible to get the password? If not, how can I remove those balances from my account?

Thank

Answer (score 2):

**It's a scam**. They are showing you addresses that they don't actually have private keys for in order to trick you into thinking that you will be able to make money. It's practically the same thing as the traditional Nigerian Prince scam.

---

Think about it: if someone had all of that money and could give you the private key, why wouldn't they just take it themselves? Why would they give it to someone else in exchange for a small payment?

---

TL;DR **IT'S A SCAM**